# How to ignore all keyboard events on Chrome for Android?

Tags: javascript, android, browser, keyboard, dom-events

It's easy on any desktop browser. I just listen for `keydown` of `document` or `window`, and call `preventDefault`, as with the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628081/how-to-disable-full-keyboard-keys-using-javascript-or-jquery) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269927/keyboard-freezing-in-web-application-using-javascript).

I usually use something like this, so it's like ignoring all keyboard inputs:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}, true);
```

But they don't work on my Android tablet. (Tested on Chrome 63.0.3239.83 and Firefox 57.0.1 for Android)

---

Here is the typical scenario: I have an `<input>` focused as the current active element, and then I need some JavaScript to execute to freeze the user interface so all user inputs are ignored.

---

I wasted a lot of time on this issue and still cannot find a workaround for my Android tablet.

I considered some other ways, like changing focus to another element, or setting `readOnly` of the element to `true`. But there are caveats. Calling `focus()` triggers the `onblur` of the previously focused element. Setting `readOnly` does not prevent the event listeners of the focused element from firing (e.g. any `keydown` or `keyup` handlers for that `<input>`), and sometimes the enter key becomes a key that allows user to jump to the next input field on the page.

Is there a way to ignore all keyboard inputs on Chrome for Android without undesirable side effects?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to a related problem, I want to move the focus to the next input when some character is pressed. On chrome on android the focus is moved, but the next input receives the character, even if preventDefault() is called. Still looking ...

Answer (score 0):

At last I called `window.addEventListener` to attach the same handler (the function used in the question) for not only `keydown`, but also `blur` and `focus`, and then called `document.documentElement.focus()`. (Need to add `tabindex="0"` to `<html>`)

This avoids the problem of triggering `onblur` of the previously focused element, which is mentioned in the question.

(Note that [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur) and [`focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focus) are not cancelable events, so handlers are only for stopping propagation here.)